# Mysql: Insert and Update both are observed really slow on my local machine

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

This is Uday. I have a problem with the write performance with a small innodb table.

```
    There is a table called "wlists" on my local machine(mysql 5.1.X).
    It has 5 attributes and has less than 1000 rows. 
    By default, innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit is set to 1 ;

    Now the thing is that
    every insert/update it is taking 0.04 seconds, 
    this is horrible because i can do just 54K inserts per hour.

    When innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit set to 2, its working fine.
```

What to do to get the same performance with innodb_flush attribute set to 1 only..?

```
    Here are some other details that may help in addressing this:
    load on the machine       : Quite normal
    innodb_log_file_size      : 1MB
    innodb_buffer_pool_size   : 8MB
    innodb_thread_concurrency : 8 
    Query                     : update wlists set customer_id = 1000 where id = 300;
```

I have tried different options like OPTIMIZE table, increasing the log buffer, checking the network latency but no one worked. I would be really thankfull to those who would help me here.

Here are the DESC and EXPLAIN of the table.

```
    mysql> DESC wlists ; 
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
    | customer_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
    | name        | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
    | created     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
    | modified    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

    mysql> explain select customer_id from wlists where id = 300 ;
    +----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+
    | id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
    ----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | wishlists | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const         |    1 |       | 
    +----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

SELECT is working OK. Problem is only with the UPDATE/INSERT.

Regards,
UDAY

Comment: Without a schema and a list of indexes, it's very very hard to even guess. Very many indexes could be a cause for example.

Comment: Post the output of `explain update wlists set customer_id = 1000 where id = 300;`

Comment: Joachim & freck, I have updated the required. -Uday

Comment: using TRANSACTIONS would bring significant performance.                                                                I mean to say, rather than doing 1 by 1, keep a bunch of SQL's in a single TRANSACTION which would work like innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2 for all that 1000 or 2000 what ever. - Uday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit set to 1 will always cause performance slowdown on writes because InnoDB will wait for the operating system to return with disk success after each operation. Though, note that the operating system will sometimes lie based on its own caching.

But setting innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit == 1 is also the only way to guarantee ACID and full data recovery (assuming the OS doesn't lie too much). So it's a tradeoff. The ideal way to deal with this is to have a battery-backed up storage system that has its own write caching. That way you get the advantage of write-caching without data recovery issues. Though of course you then have to make sure the battery backup is fully maintained, and you'll have write speed issues when the battery goes through regular maintenance cycles.

Comment: Thanq Kernel. It seems right. But 50 - 60K per hour on a table with 1000 rows and going for these options, it seems not good. I feel there is something else behind this behavior.

Comment: @Uday: I think there is something else behind this too. I have two machines the newer machine is higher spec in every way, measured disk writes are twice as fast on newer server and yet the speed of a MySQL update on newer server is ~100 times slower than the old server. I have had to set innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 to allow the database to be usable. The slow server is MySQL 5.1.61-log running on CentOS 6.2 64 bit kernel 2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.x86_64, Can you let me know your setup to see if there is any common ground. I am not finding very much on line about this specific problem.

Comment: Hi Richard, I have observed the same behavior both on 32 bit and 64 bit. mine is ubuntu 8.10. what is the EXPLAIN plan saying about the equivalent SELECT of your update. do u mean INSERTs also slow as your updates...?

Comment: @Uday: EXPLAIN is same results as yours. INSERTs are slow too. I have been comparing all mysql settings to another server that does not have same symptoms and have found nothing different. The only change that "fixes" the speed issue is innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 but disk writes (even calling sync) are twice fast on server with slow MySQL inset/update. SELECT queries are fast. The affected version of MySQL is 5.1.61-log. I wonder if it is just a bug in this version and installing a different version would be a solution. What version is your MySQL?

Comment: So it seems it is not the problem with rpm or disc write capability. I redo the same test on my local server. it is like when i set the flus value to 1, it is 30 -40 inserts per second and when i switch to 2, it is 1000 - 2000 inserts per second. I am trying to dig in what can be the readon. i guess some thing at config level is the reason.

Comment: I am using the same configuration on 6 front line servers all running the same application. The only differences are the version of MySQL and the hardware. The underlying disk I/O is twice as fast on this server as other 5 servers. The mysql insert/update speed is 100 times slower on this server than others unless I use the innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2  option. I have also just tested using the standard my-huge.cnf settings and is still just as slow, which to me rules out a configuration option. I suspect the MySQL version has a bug. What version of MySQL are you running? Is it 5.1.61 ?

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112665/5-1-61-0ubuntu0-10-04-1-performance-issues - although closed as off topic .

Comment: Possibly related: http://serverfault.com/questions/216123/mysql-innodb-inserts-very-slow - suggests InnoDB may be broken.

Comment: I have replaced the installed 5.1.61 with 5.1.54 and the problem remains.